# Sublime Text Preferences

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

http://dbader.org/blog/setting-up-sublime-text-for-python-development

I am getting this error: Error trying to parse settings: Expected value in ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings:2:5

My preferences right now look like this:

```
{
# Colors
"color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Solarized (Dark).tmTheme",
"theme": "Soda Dark.sublime-theme",

# Font
"font_face": "Arial",
"font_size": 18.0,
"font_options": ["subpixel_antialias", "no_bold"],
"line_padding_bottom": 0,
"line_padding_top": 0,

# Cursor style - no blinking and slightly wider than default
#"caret_style": "solid",
#"wide_caret": "true",

# Editor view look-and-feel
"draw_white_space": "all",
"fold_buttons": "false",
"highlight_line": "false",
"auto_complete": "true",
"show_minimap": "false",

# Editor behavior
"scroll_past_end": "false",
"highlight_modified_tabs": "true",
"find_selected_text": "true",

# Word wrapping - follow PEP 8 recommendations
"rulers": [ 72, 79 ],
"word_wrap": "true",
"wrap_width": 80,

# Whitespace - no tabs, trimming, end files with \n
"tab_size": 4,
"translate_tabs_to_spaces": "true",
"trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": "true",
"ensure_newline_at_eof_on_save": "true",

# Sidebar - exclude distracting files and folders
"file_exclude_patterns":
[
    ".DS_Store",
    "*.pid",
    "*.pyc"
],
"folder_exclude_patterns":
[
    ".git",
    "__pycache__",
    "env",
    "env3"
]
}
```

Any idea what this error means and how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sublime Text uses JSON in the configuration file. And it supports `//` style comments. So please change `#` to `//`.

[Support comments in JSON config files](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=9723)